# How to do mannual traversing in router?

Tags: spring-integration

A `<int:splitter>` which returns list of record to the `<int:router>` then router process record one by one.I don't want to process the record if KEY is NULL.
How can i skip the record if key is NULL?
How i will manually  traverse to next record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i can fix this issue after adding `resolution-required="false"`  `default-output-channel="configErrorChannel"` property to my router.so whenever KEY is null it goes to error channel.

Answer (score 0):

Add a [filter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#filter) between the splitter and router. If you are later aggregating the results, though, you will need custom strategies, to deal with the "holes" in the sequence.